# Html.BeginForm post null model

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, razor

I have created a create page using asp.net scafolding and below is my page to create expenses.

```
@model ExpenCare.Models.ExpenseCategory

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CreateExpenseCategories";
}

<div class="row">
    @Html.Partial("_RightSidePane")
    <div class="col-10 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 col-md-10">
        <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="list-Profile-Content" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-Profile">

                @using (Html.BeginForm("CreateExpenseCategories", "Admin", FormMethod.Post))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <h4>ExpenseCategory</h4>
                        <hr />
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Expense, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Expense, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Expense, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

On create this page post data to CreateExpenseCategories method of Admin controller.

```
public ActionResult CreateExpenseCategories(ExpenseCategory expense)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:1888/api/");

            var responseTask = client.PostAsJsonAsync("ExpenseCategories", expense);
            responseTask.Wait();

            var result = responseTask.Result;
            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("ExpenseCategories");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Server Error. Please contact administrator.");
            }
            return View("ExpenseCategories/CreateExpenseCategories", model: expense);
        }
```

The model used to create this page is as below,

```
namespace ExpenCare.Models
{
    public class ExpenseCategory
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Expense { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public Company Company { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I create an expense this always give null exception error and when I debug, the posted data model is null. This must be a small issue for sure, because I have done other create pages in similar way and I did nit encounter any issue. I must be missing a small thing and this might be a stupid question, but I can't find why this gives a null exception error on post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the usage of Html.EditorFor,

Try this

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model => model.Expense,new { @class = "form-control" })
```

or

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Expense,null,"Expense",new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } } )
```

> Edit problem solved

Property on type ExpenseCategory has the same parameter 'expense'. Change

```
public ActionResult CreateExpenseCategories(ExpenseCategory expense)
```

to

```
public ActionResult CreateExpenseCategories(ExpenseCategory model)
```

Comment: Property on type ExpenseCategory has the same parameter 'expense'.
Change 

public ActionResult CreateExpenseCategories(ExpenseCategory expense)
to 
public ActionResult CreateExpenseCategories(ExpenseCategory model)

Comment: @shamila I changed to my answer in post. Can you apply it?

Answer (score 1):

In your model the Id field is not null able Probably you should add an input or hidden input for it to correct model binding:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
```

**Revise:**
I test this case and model binding in mvc is working and setting *default value* for id. Entirely in absence of an input in form  model binding in mvc still working. This behavior is sense because all fields by default are optional and we can set required attribute to enforce inputting them.

Comment: Can't add Id in create since it is auto generating in database when saving data

Comment: OK that's right. However it's best practice to distinct view model from data model.